# Why is my query not using "Missing index tip"? ( SQL Server 2008 R2 )

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index, where

I know there's a lot of questions like this one, but I think this is different, and none of them could help me.

When I run a query with execution plan, I get this:

[image]

But, even with the index created, it's not using it.

The funny thing is, when I create it in my test environment (same database, same query, same index), it uses it.

Why is my production server not using the index I've created?

[image]

This is the same query in my test environment with the same index in the same database.

It's a simple query:

```
select * 
from Database 
where col1 = 'string'
  and col2 = 'string'
```

The index I created is:

```
create index (ix_col1_col2)
on Table (col1, col2)
```

Edit 1:

With Aaron's answers, I now have this:

[image]

I have the same result with `*` and using all fields.

The server still want me to create the same index it's already using. it's because the 0%? it thinks the query it's not using it?

EDIT 3:

What a strange thing. I used this:

```
alter index all on table rebuild
```

and update stats, and now, the query is using the index with 50% CPU.

Is this a good question to help others? or we should close it? since it was a simple problem.

Again thanks Aaron for your help.

Comment: Try adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the query. It is possible that the plan you are getting is stuck in a version prior to the index existing. It is also possible that because of the number of rows that match, and the fact that you're using SELECT * and so the index doesn't cover your query, that in one environment the other index is still the better choice.

Comment: It can be Aaron. I will update my question with I got. The query now is using the index, but with 99% CPU in the PK, and still tells me to add the missing index ( the same one ).

Comment: It is doing a key lookup - meaning your index is not covered. Can you post the relevant colums.

Comment: @Kin, This is the query: 
`select * from Table where idChamada = '18/09/15 09:08:19 010A 7E09/00' and evento = 'EVENTO_DE_COMPLETAMENTO'`

Comment: Table columns: `ID|
Data|
IDChamada|
Evento|
Resposta|
IDTarifador|
ProximoEvento`

Comment: the index:

`idchamada,evento`

Comment: Also, is ID defined as primary key ?

Comment: @kin Yes, ID is the PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table creation :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1
    (         [ID]              int primary key
            , [Data]            varchar(20)
            , [IDChamada]       varchar(50)
            , [Evento]          varchar(50)
            , [Resposta]        varchar(10)
            , [IDTarifador]     int
            , [ProximoEvento]   varchar(10))
;
```

You can bloat the table

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Table1 WITH ROWCOUNT = 10000000, pagecount = 10000000
```

With your given index

```
create nonclustered index nc_idChamada_evento_Rafael on dbo.table1 ( idchamada,evento)
```

SQL Server is going to do a [KEY LOOKUP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326635(v=sql.105).aspx) to find other columns from your SELECT list

```
select [ID]
    ,[Data]
    ,[IDChamada]
    ,[Evento]
    ,[Resposta]
    ,[IDTarifador]
    ,[ProximoEvento]
from dbo.Table1
where idChamada = '18/09/15 09:08:19 010A 7E09/00'
    and evento = 'EVENTO_DE_COMPLETAMENTO'
```

[image]

Key Lookup is done on below columns since they are part of select query :

[image]

The index you need is

```
create nonclustered index nc_idChamada_evento_KIN on dbo.table1 (
    idchamada
    ,evento
    ) include (
    [Data]
    ,[Resposta]
    ,[IDTarifador]
    ,[ProximoEvento]
    )
```

Above index will give you a nice seek :

[image]